# Excel vba vlookup range in multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to do a vlookup into another Workbook using VBA. 
It's working without any issues, but now I would like it not only to look at a  single cell, but loop through a range. Let's say T15:T200.

Anyone who can help modify the code to do this?

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooksBACKUP()

    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim srchRange As Range

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook

    Dim book2Name As String
    book2Name = "testbog.xlsx"

    Dim book2NamePath As String
    book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

    Set book1 = ThisWorkbook

    If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)
    Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)


    Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(15, 20)   ' value to find
    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("A:B")    'source

    lookFor.Offset(0, 20).Value = Application.Vlookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include a loop in the last part of your code, and use the loop counter variable instead of `15`:

```
'...
    Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)
    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("A:B")    'source
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 15 To 200
        Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(r, 20)   ' value to find

        lookFor.Offset(0, 20).Value = Application.Vlookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for taking my `Vlookup` baby, but you forget to handle the scenarios where `Vlookup` won't find a match and you'll get an error

Comment: @ShaiRado If `Application.VLookup` fails to match, it will return an error (equivalent to a `#N/A`), and the cell will be set to that `#N/A` error condition.  That seems a reasonable way to signify that the `VLookup` failed.